# Functional analysis in R with fda

Tags: r, splines, functional-data-analysis, dose-response

I'm working with time series data for drug response. And, I wanted to as is there are some alternative ways to analyse it since the FDA package in R is not working in my case.

The type of my data is as follows:

```
> head(subset_df)
# A tibble: 6 × 4
# Groups:   Model, Drug [1]
  Model   Day   AUC Drug   
  <chr> <int> <dbl> <chr>  
1 AB050     1 0.241 (+)-KT5
2 AB050     3 0.505 (+)-KT5
3 AB050     4 0.598 (+)-KT5
4 AB050     5 0.675 (+)-KT5
5 AB050     6 0.712 (+)-KT5
6 AB050     7 0.734 (+)-KT5

> str(subset_df)
gropd_df [102 × 4] (S3: grouped_df/tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ Model: chr [1:102] "AB050" "AB050" "AB050" "AB050" ...
 $ Day  : int [1:102] 1 3 4 5 6 7 0 1 2 3 ...
 $ AUC  : num [1:102] 0.251 0.515 0.608 0.685 0.722 ...
 $ Drug : chr [1:102] "(+)-KT5" "(+)-KT5" "(+)-KT5" "(+)-KT5" ...
 - attr(*, "groups")= tibble [17 × 3] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
  ..$ Model: chr [1:17] "AB050" "AB666K" "AB8789" "AB1578" ...
  ..$ Drug : chr [1:17] "(+)-KT56" "(+)-KT56" "(+)-KT56" "(+)-KT56" ...
  ..$ .rows: list<int> [1:17] 


xyplot(AUC ~ Day, data = subset_df, groups = Model,
       type = "l", xlim = c(0,7), auto.key = list(columns = 4))
```

[image]

This plot represents a subset data for a single drug; each line depicts a Model tested with that single drug across time and the y-axis is the AUC value estimated at that time. In general, we have 50 drugs with different models as well.

So what I would like to do is an analysis of each Model across time in a functional analysis way in R. In the sense of representing each Model curve as a function and be able to kind of estimate a pattern of the drugs based on the estimated functions for each model.

This is what I have tried so far, but without luck:

```
#Tried to create a list of functional data objects that the fda package requires for each curve:


fdobj_list <- lapply(unique(subset_df$Model), function(model) {
  model_df <- subset_df[subset_df$Model == model, ]
  basisobj <- create.bspline.basis(rangeval = range(model_df$Day), nbasis = 10)
  fdParobj <- fdPar(basisobj, lambda = 1e-4)
  Data2fd(model_df, argvals = model_df$Day, y = model_df$AUC, fdPar = fdParobj)
})
```

But I cannot make it work:. I do not know if I am missing the convergence of the fda or the data set is weird. I am quite lost hehe

Do you know if this a good way to analyse this data or is it better to approach it with B-spline, or how can I analyse it.

Thanks in advance.

> **Update**

Ok, reading the paper

https://bmcmedresmethodol.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s12874-019-0666-3

I tried to implement the Bspline approach:

```
library(bspline)
library(spline)

model_names <- unique(subset_df$Model)

# Define the B-spline function
bspline_fun <- function(x, knots) {
  bs(x, degree = 3, knots = knots, intercept = FALSE)
}

bspline_df <- data.frame()

# Loop through each Model and fit a B-spline curve
for (i in 1:length(model_names)) {
  
  # Subset the data for the current Model
  model_data <- subset_df[subset_df$Model == model_names[i],]
  
  # Fit a B-spline curve using the bspline function
  bspline_fit <- bspline_fun(model_data$Day, knots = c(min(model_data$Day), median(model_data$Day), max(model_data$Day)))
  
  # Create a data frame with the fitted curve and model name
  bspline_model <- data.frame(Day = model_data$Day, AUC = predict(bspline_fit))
  bspline_model$Model <- model_names[i]
  
  # Add the fitted curve to the data frame
  bspline_df <- rbind(bspline_df, bspline_model)
}

# Gather the AUC columns into a single column
bspline_df <- gather(bspline_df, key = "AUC_id", value = "AUC", AUC.1:AUC.6)

# Plot the fitted curves
xyplot(AUC ~ Day | Model, data = bspline_df, groups = AUC_id, type = "l", auto.key = list(columns = length(unique(bspline_df$AUC_id))))


# Plot the fitted curves
xyplot(AUC ~ Day, data = bspline_df, type = "l", auto.key = list(columns = length(model_names)))
```

I get bizarre results....
Do you know what happened here? :

[image]

Another simpler approach is just by plotting the smooth lines:

```
library(splines)
library(lattice)

# Get unique Model names
model_names <- unique(subset_df$Model)

# Create a color palette
my_colors <- c("#1B9E77", "#D95F02", "#7570B3", "#E7298A", "#66A61E", "#E6AB02", "#A6761D", "#666666", 
                        "#D53E4F", "#3288BD", "#C51B7D", "#80CDC1", "#F781BF", "#984EA3", "#FFFF33", "#E41A1C", "#034E7B")
                        
# Create an empty list to store fitted curves
spline_list <- list()

# Loop through each Model and fit a spline curve
for (i in 1:length(model_names)) {
  
  # Subset the data for the current Model
  model_data <- subset_df[subset_df$Model == model_names[i],]
  
  # Fit a spline curve using the smooth.spline function
  spline_fit <- smooth.spline(model_data$Day, model_data$AUC, df = 5)
  
  # Add the fitted curve to the list
  spline_list[[i]] <- spline_fit
  
}

# Plot the fitted curves
xyplot(AUC ~ Day, data = subset_df, groups = Model, type = c("p", "smooth"), 
       panel = function(x, y, groups, subscripts, ...) {
         panel.superpose(x, y, groups = groups[subscripts], subscripts = subscripts, ...)
         for (i in subscripts) {
           col <- my_colors[i %% length(my_colors) + 1]
           llines(predict(spline_list[[i]], x), col = col, lwd = 2)
         }
       },
       key = list(space = "bottom", text = list(model_names), points = FALSE, 
                  lines = TRUE, col = my_colors[1:length(model_names)], lwd = 2))
```

But I got problems plotting this...:

[image]

> > **Update**

I tried to follow this lecture: https://www.r-users.gal/sites/default/files/fda_usc.pdf

But the fda.usc package showed tons of errors...

> > > **Update**

```
plot_obj <- NULL

# Iterate over each unique Model in the data frame
for (model in unique(subset_df$Model)) {
  
  # Subset the data frame to only include the current model
  model_df <- subset_df[subset_df$Model == model, ]
  
  # Estimate the smoothing spline for the current model
  spline_fit <- with(model_df, smooth.spline(Day, AUC))
  
  # Add the spline fit to the plot object
  plot_obj <- xyplot(AUC ~ Day, data = model_df, type = "p", main = model,
                     xlab = "Day", ylab = "AUC",
                     auto.key = list(lines = TRUE, points = FALSE),
                     panel = function(x, y, ...) {
                       panel.xyplot(x, y, ...)
                       panel.lines(spline_fit$x, spline_fit$y, col = "red")
                     },
                     add = plot_obj)
}

print(plot_obj)
```

But I am not getting the smooth line...
[image]

Sorry for the problems.... Any insights and help is very welcome... Thanks...

Comment: There are two possible confusions in terminology. First, you are using "AUC" as [pharmacokinetic terminology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Area_under_the_curve_(pharmacokinetics)), while on this site "AUC" typically means the area under a [receiver operating characteristic curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic). Second, it's not clear what you mean by multiple models for the same drug. Are they different models of raw drug concentrations over time, different animal models, or...? Please edit the question to clarify those matters.

Comment: Yes, here it is just one drug and each line is a different cell line tested for that particular drug, the AUC it is how we named it. In this case it is not necessary the dose, because it is already estimated by the AUC value. I do not want to know if the drug responded well or not, I just want to convert each curve Model into a function.

Comment: What I understand: you have cell lines ("Models") each treated with a set of drugs. What you call the "AUC" is something related to the number of cells: e.g., you plate a small number of cells on Day 0 and follow something related to their numbers or mass or metabolic activity (like on [this web page](https://www.cancerrxgene.org/help#t_curve)) each day. You want a mathematical way to express the time course of that "AUC". If so, please edit the question to include that; comments can be overlooked.

Comment: It also would help if you could provide in the question a small sample of a full data set, instead of the partial summary that you show. For example, maybe for 5 cell lines show values for all 8 days for a small number of drugs (2 or 3). That would give others something directly from your data to play with. Otherwise we would have to try to generate data that might not represent your actual situation.

Comment: The `x` and `y` components of your `spline_fit` object are just the original `x` values and their corresponding predicted`y` values. If you want a full smooth curve you have to use the `predict()` function on the `spline_fit` object, along with a sequence of new `x` values, say about 100 of them. The `predict()` function then returns those new `x` values along with the corresponding `y` predictions. See how I set up and used the `newDays` variable in my answer with the `ss1` smooth spline fit. Consult the help page for the `predict.smooth.spline` function that works on those smooths.

Comment: You could, for example, use: `newDays <- seq(0,7,length.out=100); spline_interp <- predict(spline_fit, newDays)`. Then use `spline_interp` instead of `spline_fit` in your call to `xyplot()`. That will give you 100 points instead of only 8, which usually looks pretty smooth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things going on here. I don't use the `fda` package, and highly software-specific questions are off topic here, but there seems to be some confusion about how splines are implemented.

Here is a single set of `AUC` versus `Day` data that seem similar to yours. When things aren't working, start with a single simple example before you make things more complicated.

```
aucData
#   Day  AUC
# 1   0 0.00
# 2   1 0.10
# 3   2 0.30
# 4   3 0.35
# 5   4 0.40
# 6   5 0.38
# 7   6 0.45
# 8   7 0.42
```

With only 8 data points for each combination of "Model" and "Drug" you will be limited in the quality of any fit. Even the simple models below with only 3 or 4 coefficients might well be over-fitting the data. Be very wary of over-interpretation.

One problem (maybe the biggest) with your work so far is that functions like `bs()` or your `bspline_fun()` only define a model matrix for the predictor that can be used to fit a regression spline. They don't fit anything directly. Here's an example with a single interior knot at the median `Day` value (as far as I might be comfortable going with only 8 observations).

```
library(splines)
bs(aucData$Day,knots=3.5)
#                1          2           3           4
# [1,] 0.000000000 0.00000000 0.000000000 0.000000000
# [2,] 0.530612245 0.09912536 0.005830904 0.000000000
# [3,] 0.571428571 0.30320700 0.046647230 0.000000000
# [4,] 0.367346939 0.47230321 0.157434402 0.000000000
# [5,] 0.157434402 0.47230321 0.367346939 0.002915452
# [6,] 0.046647230 0.30320700 0.571428571 0.078717201
# [7,] 0.005830904 0.09912536 0.530612245 0.364431487
# [8,] 0.000000000 0.00000000 0.000000000 1.000000000
## reports of attributes omitted
```

This matrix shows how each of the 8 `Day` values (rows) are represented in terms of the 4 predictors (columns) for which coefficients would be reported in a model. You then have to fit the `AUC` values against this basis representation of the `Day` values:

```
bs1 <- lm(AUC~bs(Day,knots=3.5),data=aucData)
```

The smoothing spline works a bit differently. It places a knot at each data point and then penalizes the wiggliness of the curve to take into account the number of data points. Here's the default for these data.

```
ss1 <- with(aucData,smooth.spline(Day,AUC))
ss1
# Call:
# smooth.spline(x = Day, y = AUC)
# 
# Smoothing Parameter  spar= 0.4433949  lambda= 0.002846502 (14 iterations)
# Equivalent Degrees of Freedom (Df): 3.748625
# Penalized Criterion (RSS): 0.005042357
# GCV: 0.002231849
```

In this case, either seems to represent the data adequately.

```
plot(AUC~Day,data=aucData,type="l",bty="n")
newDays <- seq(0,7,length.out=100)
lines(newDays,predict(bs1,newdata=list(Day=newDays)),col="red")
lines(predict(ss1,newDays),col="blue") ## predict() works a bit differently here
legend("topleft",legend="black, raw data\nred, bs\nblue, ss",bty="n")
```

[image: Plot of data, bs and ss fits]

I suspect that some of your data time courses are wigglier than this, so that you get wigglier curves that look troubling. If, as I suspect, the data represent some type of ideally non-decreasing growth curve that is subject to some measurement error, the spline fits in those cases might not make much sense at all. You might see a hint of that in the red curve for the `bs` fit, which starts pointing upward at the last `Day`. Don't try to inspect all of your curves at once, as you seem to be doing.

If there's a general theoretical form that might be expected to describe the data, you might be better off with a nonlinear fit of an appropriate parametric model. For example, a logistic growth curve can often represent such data; there's a built-in `SSlogis()` function that can simplify the fitting:

```
nlsLogis <- nls(AUC~SSlogis(Day,Asym,xmid,scale),data=aucData)
nlsLogis
# Nonlinear regression model
#   model: AUC ~ SSlogis(Day, Asym, xmid, scale)
#    data: aucData
#   Asym   xmid  scale 
# 0.4078 1.5654 0.5153 
#  residual sum-of-squares: 0.004432
```

Here `Asym` is the upper asymptote; `xmid` is the `Day` value at which you reach half of that, and `scale` sets the steepness of the curve. You can display that if you choose (not shown here) via:

```
lines(newDays,predict(nlsLogis,newdata=list(Day=newDays)))
```

If this logistic growth model is appropriate, this provides a simple closed-form function for the AUC against time, with readily interpretable coefficients (unlike those in spline fits).

$$\text{AUC} = \frac{\text{Asym}}{1+\exp\left((\text{xmid}-\text{Day})/\text{scale}\right)}$$

That would seem ideal for "functional data analysis," if that functional form is appropriate.

Comment: Hi @EdM, I tried to implement the nls() approach but I get too many singularties due to the nature of my data. Though, I tried also the with() approach but I cannot manage to make it happen for all the models I have. Could you have a look on my code that I put as an update, please? thanks a lot again.

Comment: @RosaMaria I commented on your plotting problem under the question itself. The big problem is that, with only 8 data points per Model/drug combination, a little irregularity in just a couple of points can make nonlinear parametric fits less than reliable and make smoothing splines takes some weird twists.